# TADO, Access, TNavigator Delete Record Exception

Tags: delphi

How to solve a TADO, Access, TNavigator Delete Record Exception"Key column information is insufficient or incorrect"?

Comment: Could you provide a code example?  Ideally, create a small example application that generates this error (to help readers focus on the problem).

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the key that your database components are using to access the table is not enough to identify a unique record. Make sure you give your table a primary key or at least a field with a unique index enforced.